# On the $n^{th}$ day he puts $n$ pennies into the same jar. Which day is the first day on which he has at least $20$ dollars in the jar?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

On the first day, Daniel puts one penny into the jar. On the second day he puts $2$ pennies into the same jar.

On the $n^{th}$ day he puts $n$ pennies into the same jar. Which day is the first day on which he has at least $20$ dollars in the jar? (1-dollar = $100$ pennies)

#### Progress

Since $20$ dollars is $2000$ pennies, I tried to solve $n(n-1)/2=2000$ and I got 62.7 so 63 day. How do I find the exact amount on the 63rd day?

Comment: I tried n(n-1)/2=2000 but the answer is too big

Comment: That is the right formula the answer is 63 days. At 62 days you have \$19.53 and at 63 \$20.16.

Comment: Since it says **"at least"** you need to use an inequality symbol.

Comment: Ok, I got 63 now. But how did you figure out how much money is in the jar at 63? Which formula did you use for that?

Comment: The right formula is $\dfrac {n\cdot (n+1)}{2}\ge 2000$

Comment: Yes I did that, but now I want to know how to find the exact amount of money for the 63rd day

Comment: You use the same formula. Plug in $n = 63$ into $$\frac{n \cdot (n + 1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the $63$rd day, you have $1+2+3+\dots+63=T_{63}$, the $63$rd [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), which equals $\frac 12(63)(63+1)=2016$ pennies

Comment: Ok that's what I did. My calculator had a bug so I reset it and now it works! Thanks!